# Jest regex to match certain test files

Tags: jestjs

I have integration tests under dir `src/test/integration`. All files are named like so: `foo.integration.js`.

Running Jest:

```
jest ".*\\.integration\\.js"
```

produces this error:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/dangruszczyk/workspace/cef/lambda-workflow
  7 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 7 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern: .*\.integration\.js - 0 matches
```

Surely this regex should match `src/test/integration/foo.integration.js` (https://regex101.com/r/T3WJwd/1/). Any clue why it does not?

Comment: Why not just `jest integration`?

Comment: Even simpler but still won't find these tests. I think Jest requires test files to end in `t(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)` and then runs any additional regex on files that match that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Jest is still applying the `testMatch`, i.e. you're filtering within the files it has already determined to be test files, and `src/test/integration/foo.integration.js` matches neither `**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)` nor `**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)`*.

To run those files, you're probably best off setting the [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) instead:

```
jest --testMatch='**/*.integration.js'
```

This doesn't seem to be a documented part of the CLI, but works fine (for now!) in practice.

* *Interestingly, neither does `path/to/my-test.js`, the example shown in [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#running-from-the-command-line)...*

Comment: Brilliant. I saw that and I suspected that's the case. However, when checking Jest CLI docs there's no mention of being able to replace `testMatch`. Thanks

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk yes, I was just looking for the same thing to link the docs... It makes me wonder if that's a reliable part of the CLI!

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, really helpful. This probably won't fit their bug profile but maybe it will prompt some action https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12261.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same thing, but in the end it felt more natural to restructure.

By using `.test.js` you can easily run **all tests** or **selectively filter sub-types**.

```
example.integration.test.js
example.unit.test.js
```

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test-all": "jest",
    "unit-test": "jest \"--testPathPattern='.+\\.unit\\.test\\.js$'\"",
    "integration-test": "jest \"--testPathPattern='.+\\.integration\\.test\\.js$'\""
  },
```

As others have said, jest expects test files to end `.test.js` or `.spec.js`.